# Assign Task action used for document set approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm currently trying to create a custom workflow in SPD 2013 and I want to create a task that allows approvers to accept or reject and then change a column in the list to reflect the choice, is this the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I suggest you create a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow, then design it like the below:
[image]

Note: You need to change Title in "Set Field in Current Item" to your column.